# SQL Server : datediff from last week

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and have a statement that returns these records for the current week:

```
Employee , Sun , Mon , Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat 
--------------------------------------------------
 Smith      5     8      5    4     8     4    0
 Burt       7     1      8    5     4     4    7
```

This is my SQL and the week starts on a Sun. How do I change so it shows the previous week?

```
SELECT
    ReproofMidLineBy AS Employee,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN DATENAME( dw, ReproofMidLineDate )= 'Sunday' THEN 1 END ) AS Sun,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN DATENAME( dw, ReproofMidLineDate )= 'Monday' THEN 1 END ) AS Mon,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN DATENAME( dw, ReproofMidLineDate )= 'Tuesday' THEN 1 END ) AS Tues,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN DATENAME( dw, ReproofMidLineDate )= 'Wednesday' THEN 1 END ) AS Wed,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN DATENAME( dw, ReproofMidLineDate )= 'Thursday' THEN 1 END ) AS Thurs,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN DATENAME( dw, ReproofMidLineDate )= 'Friday' THEN 1 END ) AS Fri,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN DATENAME( dw, ReproofMidLineDate )= 'Saturday' THEN 1 END ) AS Sat,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
    dbo.tblJobLog
WHERE
    (ReproofMidLineDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, 0) 
                        AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 6, GETDATE()- 1) / 7 * 7 + 7, 6)
     )
GROUP BY
    ReproofMidLineBy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your where clause with this:

```
    WHERE
(
    ReproofMidLineDate BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -1, DATEADD(
        DAY,
        DATEDIFF(
            DAY,
            0,
            GETDATE()
        )/ 7 * 7,
        0))


    AND DATEADD(WEEK, -1, DATEADD(
        DAY,
        DATEDIFF(
            DAY,
            6,
            GETDATE()- 1
        )/ 7 * 7 + 7,
        6
    ))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A really easy way would be to add one week for the comparison:

```
WHERE DATEADD(week, 1, ReproofMidLineDate) BETWEEN . . .
```

You could also subtract one week (or 7 days) from the bounds of the `BETWEEN`.